# Why does $y'' + y = 0$ contain essential singularity at $z =\infty$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'' + y = 0$ has sine and cosine solutions. It has no regular singularities, although it has an essential singularity at $z \to \infty$ because if you let 
$$w = \frac{1}{z}$$ 
$$\frac{dy}{dz} = \frac{dy}{dw}\frac{dw}{dz} = -w^2\frac{dy}{dw}$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dz^2} = -\frac{d}{dw} \left(w^2\frac{dy}{dw}\right) \frac{dw}{dz} = w^3\left(2\frac{dy}{dw} + w\frac{d^2y}{dw^2}\right)$$

Now I evaluate the behavior $w \to 0$; $z \to \infty$. Plugging these new differentials into the previous differential equation I get

$$w^4\frac{d^2y}{dw^2} + 2w^3\frac{dy}{dw} + y = 0$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dw^2} + \frac{2}{w}\frac{dy}{dw} + \frac{1}{w^4}y = 0$$

This contains an essential singularity at $z =\infty$. I'm not quite sure I understand why. Is it because sinusoids are not analytic at infinity? They contain no poles do they?

Edit: I don't need a formal explanation, maybe something intuitive will be more helpful.

Comment: It might help to rewrite your new ODE as $$\frac{d^2 y}{dw} + \frac{2}{w} \frac{dy}{dw} + \frac{1}{w^4} y = 0$$ for $w \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that if you solve the new differential equation, you get the general solution

$$ y(w)=c_1\sin\left(\frac{1}{w}\right)+c_2\cos\left(\frac{1}{w}\right). $$

Now, you can see the behavior of the solution at $w=0$.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very Much!

Comment: @CactusBAMF: You are welcome.

Comment: Is this just another way of saying infinity is not a true number?

Answer (score 1):

The sine and cosine functions are bounded on the real line. Therefore, they cannot have a pole at $\infty$.  They also are unbounded at $\infty$.  The singularity there is an essential singularity.

Comment: Or: $\infty$ is a cluster point of zeros of the solution.  (Any nonconstant solution.)

Comment: This works too.